# is there a better way to expand array size in c#

Tags: c#

When I run this code the array has a new size after, is there anything wrong or bad about it ?

```
static int[] ExpandArray(int[] input, int add_size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < add_size; i++)
    {
        int[] temp = input;
        input = new int[input.Length + 1];
        for (var j = 0; j < temp.Length; j++)
        {
            input[j] = temp[j];
        }
    }
    return input;
}
```

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{   
    int[] ovride = new int[3] { 1, 2, 3 };
    ovride = ExpandArray(ovride, 10);
    ovride = ExpandArray(ovride, 10);

    Console.WriteLine(ovride.Length);    
}
```

Comment: That is terribly inefficient, why are you creating new arrays inside a loop? Just create a new array with the desired size once. Or use `System.Array.Resize`

Comment: Can you not use a list?

Comment: Even though you think it might be obvious, please quantify "wrong" and "bad".

Comment: this almost looks like it's inefficient _on purpose_

Comment: thanks for letting me know not to create new arrays inside a loop, I just started c# yesterday, I don't know what a list is yet, for me "wrong" or "bad" is anything that should be obvious not  to do but is not for me because I'm new, It definitely was not my intent to make it inefficient, I was actually quite proud of my solution haha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is there anything wrong or bad about it ?

This isn't code review, but:

1. Yes. You should not resize arrays. This involves a new allocation and a copy of all elements. As does Array.Resize(), by the way.
2. Hey, there is a method that already does this: Array.Resize(). Don't reinvent the wheel.
3. You definitely should not do the resize in a loop.

So to clean up the code a little:

```
static int[] ExpandArray(int[] input, int sizeToAdd)
{
    // Create a new array with the desired size
    var ouput = new int[input.Length + sizeToAdd];
    
    // Copy all elements from input to output
    for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
    {
        output[i] = input[i];
    }

    // Return the new array, having the remaining 
    // items set to their default (0 for int)
    return output;
}
```

You'd actually want `input` to be updatable by `ref`, and then end with `input = output`.

Ultimately, just use a `List<int>`, as that allows for more efficient resizing, and does so automatically when necessary.

Comment: Just started c# yesterday and I hated how limiting having define the size of the array first was so I was trying to come up with a solution, I don't know what lists are but i suppose I'll find out later in my course. Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Array.Resize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.resize?view=net-5.0) which:

> Changes the number of elements of a one-dimensional array to the specified new size.

```cs
int[] ovride = new int[3] { 1, 2, 3 };
Array.Resize(ref ovride, ovride.Length + 10);
Array.Resize(ref ovride, ovride.Length + 10);
Console.WriteLine(ovride.Length); // prints 23
```

But if you expect collection size changes [`List`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=net-5.0) can be a more suitable option for your goal.